# Can irq smp_affinity replace the rps(receive package steering)?

Tags: affinity, smp, irq

I have a Netcard eth0，it has single queue and its IRQ number is 63，

My question is：

If I set /proc/irq/63/smp_affinity to fffff

Whether means that the Linux kernel will distribute the IRQ of eth0 to each cpu in my system?

is its function  equal to the rps(receive package steering)？

Answer (score 0):

No, the smp_affinity is a bitmask or cpu list of allowed CPUs for  this IRQ. For eg if set to 0x1 it will pin that IRQ to CPU 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

No. Setting the `smp_affinity` to `fffff` just means that the kernel can use any CPU in the `fffff` to handle IRQ 63.

If you want to distribute packet processing load with a NIC that only has a single RX queue, you have to use RPS.

Check out [a blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) I wrote about this that explains all of this and more in detail.